# Why can't Spring convert a proxy that implements a type to that type?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm running Spring 3.2.4 with Spring Security 3.1.4.  When I try deploying my app to WebLogic, I get errors.  The root error seems to be:

```
...nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot convert value of type [
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy445 implementing 
 xxx.SecurityAuditorService,
 org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,
 org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised
] 
to required type [
 xxx.SecurityAuditorService] 
for property 'securityAuditorService': 
no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
```

Here's what I don't understand...  Why can't a proxy that implements `SecurityAuditorService` be converted to the required type of `SecurityAuditorService`?

EDIT (config info):
security-common:

```
<bean id="securityAuditorService" class="xxx.SecurityAuditorServiceImpl">
   <!-- properties omitted -->
</bean>
```

SecurityAuditorServiceImpl.java

```
public class SecurityAuditorServiceImpl implements SecurityAuditorService{
   // internals omitted
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the package is the same for both classes/interfaces?

Comment: If the same class is in different classloaders it cannot be cast. If you think it is an interface but also an implementing class it cannot be cast either. A proxy of a proxy can be problematic to. Anyway make sure you aer programming to interfaces and not concrete classes. Show us the problematic code.

Comment: @Pablo: Yes, I'm sure the packages are the same.  I generated the "xxx" by doing a global replace in the editor.

Comment: @M. Deinum: SecurityAuditorService is an interface which is implemented by SecurityAuditorServiceImpl.  I'll add some config info to the question.

Comment: If the package is the same you probably have classloading issues. Class X in classloader Y is different then Class X ni Classloader Z. ALthough even if they come from the same jar. Class identity is based on the FQN + ClassLoadler not FQN alone!

Comment: @M. Deinum: That makes sense.  I suppose you have answered my question.  (Of course, my *real* question is "how do I fix this"?)

Comment: That depends on the container you use (Weblogic it seems) and the kind of archive you use (war or ear with multiple wars and shared lib or something along those lines).

Comment: @M. Deinum: I'm a bit slow, but if you convert your comment into an answer, I'll give you credit for the best answer.